# How can i fix this error in C using valgrind: invalid write of size 1

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

After compilling my code, I've got some issues regarding the memory, after doing ./valgrind on my linux terminal, I've got the following error for this function: "invalid write of size 1 at split".
Here is my function split:

```
char ** split(const char * str, const char * delim)
{
  char * s = strdup(str);
  if (strtok(s, " \n\t:") == 0){
    return NULL;}
  int nw = 1;
  while (strtok(NULL, " \n\t:") != 0)
    nw += 1;//nombre de mots
  strcpy(s, str);
  char ** v = malloc((nw + 1) * sizeof(char *));
  int i=0;
  int longueur=strcspn(s, " \n\t:");// donne la longueur de l plus petite chaine avant \n \t ou :
  v[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(longueur+2));// pour enregistrer l'étiquette avec ses deux points
  v[0]=strdup(strtok(s, " \n\t:"));// l'étiquette ne peut se trouver qu'au début sinon on signale une erreur, et si jamais on est sur une étiquette, on rajoute les :
  if(str[longueur]==':'){
     v[0][longueur]=':';
     v[0][longueur+1]='\0';
  }
  for (i = 1; i < nw; ++i)
    v[i] = strdup(strtok(NULL, " \n\t"));
  v[i] = NULL; // marque la fin du tableau, on aurait pu utiliser une structure avec comme champs le tableau et sa longueur.
  free(s);
  return v;
}
```

I don't understand where it comes from and how can I correct that to remove this error.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not related to your Valgrind message, but `return NULL;` what about freeing `s` before you leave the function? That is the next memory leak waiting for you.

Comment: The `v[0] = malloc(s ...` line followed immediately by the `v[0]=strdup(...` is also problematical. You are losing track of the memory allocated in the first.

Comment: `v[0]=strdup(` This also does not contain the extra space you added to the `malloc` call in the line above which may make `v[0][longueur+1]='\0'` illegal.

Comment: ... looks like that second line should be more like, `strcpy(v[0], strtok(s, " \n\t:"));`. I think.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @AdrianMole I love u !!!!! I went from 24 errors to 9.

Comment: [This near-duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75385508/10871073) suggests that this is a homework question. Please review [the homework guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), especially the part about possible repercussions for academic dishonesty.

Comment: @tripleee it's a project where i Have to transform document written in assembly language to a file written in hexa and then execute it. We finished it everything is working perfectly but we wanted to try valgrind to have a code as perfect as possible. Those two questions are only about that

Comment: Then why are there two questions with different broken code but identical text?

Comment: @tripleee we had 24 errors after trying valgrind on our 9 hundred lines and most of them came from this function et the one my partner posted

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix all valgrind errors:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split(const char *str, const char *delim) {
    if(!str)
        return NULL;
    char *s = strdup(str);
    if (!strtok(s, " \n\t:")) {
        free(s);
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t nw = 1;
    for(; strtok(NULL, " \n\t:"); nw++);
    strcpy(s, str);
    char **v = malloc((nw + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    size_t i=0;
    size_t longueur=strcspn(s, " \n\t:");
    v[0] = malloc(longueur+2);
    strcpy(v[0], strtok(s, " \n\t:"));
    if(str[longueur]==':'){
        v[0][longueur]=':';
        v[0][longueur+1]='\0';
    }
    for (i = 1; i < nw; i++)
        v[i] = strdup(strtok(NULL, " \n\t"));
    v[i] = NULL;
    free(s);
    return v;
}

int main() {
    char **s = split("hello:again world", " ");
    for(size_t i = 0; s && s[i]; i++) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", i, s[i]);
        free(s[i]);
    }
    free(s);
}
```

and resulting output:

```
0: hello:
1: again
2: world
```

There are a few other issues:

1. `delim` argument is not used.  Either use or eliminate it.
2. First number of tokens are counted with the delimiters " \n\t:" and then reprocessing the string after the first token with another set of delimiters " \n\t".  If you have more than 1 instance of `:` in your input string you will allocate too much space for `v`.  I suggest you just iterate over the string once and use `realloc()` to resize `v` as needed.
3. `malloc()` and `strdup()` may fail.